# Firebase iOS phone authentication "Interaction was cancelled by this user"

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase phone authentication for one of my ios app.
Its working fine almost all user.
Some of the user is getting below message, if they are trying from their mobile, same number if we try from other mobile then it works.
Is there any iPhone setting to be done to working from this mobile.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Do you have any solution for that? We are having the same issue...